# Better way to use parseInt() to change users' promt() into numbers

Tags: javascript, performance, math, random, parseint

I set up a function to ask users a range of numbers, and gave them back a random number. The first try is okay.

```js
// function settings
function getRandom(lower, upper) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(upper-lower+1))+lower;
}

// ask users to give a range of numbers
var lowerNum = parseInt(prompt("lower number?"));
var upperNum = parseInt(prompt("upper number?"));

document.write(getRandom(lowerNum, upperNum));
```

---

However, I thought it would be better to take `parseInt()` inside the function, so that it would be more clear and semantic.

```js
// function settings
function getRandom(lower, upper) {
  lower = parseInt(lower);
  upper = parseInt(upper);
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(upper-lower+1))+lower;
}

// ask users to give a range of numbers
var lowerNum = prompt("lower number?");
var upperNum = prompt("upper number?");

document.write(getRandom(lowerNum, upperNum));
```

Both blocks of codes can do well and get the same results. But which one is the **better practice**, or even performance when running the program?

Comment: Your first attempt is better.  The second attempt causes the function to have two responsibilities, not one.  The difference in performance, if any, is almost certainly negligible.

Comment: Why don't you test the performance and actually **you** tell **us**?

Comment: @Shomz I'm new to Javascript, and have no idea about performance testing. So I looked forward to some advice when writing codes. Hope you can help.

Comment: Oh, I see, this is a great site for testing performance and sharing results: https://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use whatever is more readable for you, yet if you're trying to squeeze that extra bit of performance, try cleaning elsewhere, like dropping those two temporary variables, using bitwise-flooring, etc... (looks ugly, yes):

```js
function getRandom(lower, upper) {
  return (Math.random()*(upper-lower+1) | 0) + lower;
}

alert(getRandom(parseInt(prompt("lower number?"), 10), parseInt(prompt("upper number?"), 10)));
```

---

### [Performance tests](http://jsperf.com/32216982)

You'll see your two cases are usually close to each other, my approach is slightly faster, and you go turbo when you don't parse integers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll remind myself for the word "readable" in future. :)

Comment: You're welcome, I think 'readable' is the key here because the performance difference we're talking about is nanoseconds (I plan to write a test later). :)

Comment: Yes. However, I think I have to take care of the very small difference from the beginning of building codes, so there would be a better result in performance after million lines of codes.

Comment: That's a good point, but again, it depends what your code is for - since you use prompts (waiting for user input), you don't have to worry about the under the hood performance, but it you plan to maintain the code alone as well as read hundreds of inputs from elsewhere and output random values for each, then a top-notch performance should be a priority.

Comment: If you want to remove *parseInt* entirely the *getRandom* function could use: `(Math.random()*((upper-lower)+1) | 0) + +lower`, but there should be some validation that suitable values have been provided.

Comment: @RobG No need for the two pluses since we already have an integer on the left side... `+lower + (Math.random()*((upper-lower)+1) | 0)` would make sense though.

Comment: Is `| 0` to make the whole string into number? (I've googled, but not found any ref.)

Comment: That's for turning floats into integers (by cutting the "tail"). I used it to replace your `Math.floor` calls.

Comment: @Shomz—the `+` is needed too, otherwise the string is concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

***I will preface this by saying that I am in no way sure of the correctness of this answer and it is merely an opinion based on an observation***. I believe that the performance would be negligible, but passing an int to a function would be ever so slightly faster than passing a string then parsing it into an int. The line of logic that I would use to justify this would be that a string is a more complex data type than an int.

Comment: That's a pretty bold claim, about the cost of passing primitive types as parameters.

Comment: Except he's using prompt as a string input and needs to call parseInt either outside of the function or inside the function, which is the original poster's question regarding which practice is better.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first one... not because of the parseInt, but because of the variable lookup... In the second function you are doing an extra lookup for the variables declared and initialised within your global scope.